# change a single word in a file with Bash

Tags: bash

i try to write a very simple bash file that allow my to open and modify n times a file.java .

The modification i want is only a change in a single (or two) row of a single number.

I try to do this with the follow code:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # commento

    touch ic.java

    touch input

    n=0
    for n in "1" "2" "3" "4.5"
  do
        echo 'import java.io.*;'>ic.java
        echo 'import java.util.*;'>>ic.java
        echo ' '>>ic.java
        echo 'class INITIAL_CONDITION_NORMAL {'>>ic.java
        echo 'public static void main (String args[]) {'>>ic.java
        echo "$n">>ic.java 
        n=$(($n+1))
        echo '....'>>ic.java 
 done 

       java ic.java
```

as you see i must write all the file and, when i like to change the number, put the `"$n"`
and n=$(($n+1)) in the row then go on until the end of the file and lounch it (java ic.java).

I know i can use something like:

```
sed -i 'm-th_row/old/new/' ic.java
```

but if i want to do this recursively (100 times) whit every time a different `new` value (as in the example) how can i do that?

Thanks a lot for Your help !

Comment: So you just want to run your sed command for a large number of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `new` contains no `/` (slash) character, or any other special character that would confuse `sed`, this is the sort of pattern you need.

```
for n in "1" "2" "3" "4.5"
  sed -i "m-th_row/old/$n/" ic.java
done
```

Of course, that snippet would just modify the same file repeatedly, which probably wouldn't be helpful, but you get the idea.

Comment: no it's very helpful because i must modify it then pass the new file to a program that read it and do calculation, and save the results, after that i restart this cicle so into the for cycle i put the `sed` and the program